# Parsing a CSV with ä, ö, ü

Tags: java, csv

I have a problem with reading ö,ü, and ä from a csv.The programm should read a csv-file with the OpenCSV library, then parse it to a list of customers (each row is one customer) and finally write it to another .csv-file adding additional data.

```
public CSVConverter(String fileNameIn, String fileNameOut, int header){
    try {
        this.fileNameIn = fileNameIn;
        this.fileNameOut = fileNameOut;
        this.header = header;
        reader=new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this.fileNameIn), "UTF-8"), ';');
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.fileNameOut), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSVConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


public void readTXT(){
    try {
        kundenListe = (ArrayList<String[]>) reader.readAll();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSVConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public void writeCSV(){
    this.parseCustomerList();
    for(Kunde customer : this.customerList){
        try {
            writer.write(customer.toString());
            System.out.println(customer.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CSVConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

private Kunde parseCustomer(String[] row){
    Kunde tempCust = new Kunde();
        tempCust.setKDNR(row[0].trim());
        tempCust.setName_1(row[1].trim());
        tempCust.setName_2(row[2].trim());
        //...

        return tempCust;
}
private void parseCustomerList(){
    for(String[] kunde : this.kundenListe){
            this.customerList.add(this.parseCustomer(kunde));
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to write a line from the file via `System.out.println(customer.toString());` it's also not printed, just a rectangle. But a normal `System.out.println("öäü");` works fine.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you read the file with the correct charset?

Comment: Please show your class `Kundle`

Comment: I've exported the csv-filem from access, using the UTF-8 charset. Kunde ist just a class with attributes, getters and setter, nothing else yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently cvs file, you are reading, not encoded with `UTF-8`.

Check which charset is used and use same (or replacement charset) while reading, instead of `UTF-8`

Incase it's not known or it's being generated from various systems with different encoding, you may use [this encoding detector library](https://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) to determine. Note that this API may return null in case there's no non-ASCII chars used.

Comment: I've exported the csv-file from access using the utf-8 charset.

Comment: use any advanced text editor to verify char encoding once. I suspect input CSV contains non UTF encoded chars. Basically this type of problem happens when encoded byte representation is different from what is expected by charset used for reading.

Comment: Thanks! I found the mistake! :-)